# Optical Character Recognition Development

Tags: matlab, image-processing, ocr, feature-detection, feature-extraction

I have been trying to develop an OCR engine by myself. After researching the topic a bit I have come to the conclusion that there are 4 major steps involved :

1. Pre-processing the image [de-skewing, image contrast, binarize, etc.]
2. Segment the image into the characters [to make it easier to process each character individually]
3. Identify the chracter through feature extraction / comparison and classification.
4. Post-processing the image [to increase the chances of getting an optimal solution.]

I am hopelessly lost after the 1st step! Can somebody please help me out by telling how to perform character segregation & feature extraction ? I'll be extremely grateful even if you  can provide me a link which points me in the right direction.
Thanks in advance! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a paper called self-tuning spectral clustering by Zelnik-Manor and Perona. Here is the link to their page for paper and code written in Matlab:

[Self-Tuning Spectral Clustering](http://www.vision.caltech.edu/lihi/Demos/SelfTuningClustering.html)

This method can perform image segmentation. Another thing you may want to look into is topic-modeling on images for feature extraction. Anything by Blei will also be useful.

Comment: Thank You very much for the same RDizzl3. That has proved quite helpful. :)

Answer (score 0):

The Computer Vision System Toolbox now has the [ocr](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/ref/ocr.html) function that can save you the trouble.

Comment: Hi Dima. Thanks for the same. However, our college computers have MATLAB R2013a - which doesn't have the 'ocr' functionality yet. 
Moreover, I wish to develop the OCR structure, myself, more out of interest than compulsion.

Comment: Although, I am still in the process of developing the same, I would recommend all novices of this field, akin to me, read the following book -
Character Recognition Systems - A Guide for Students and Practitioners by Cheriet, Kharma, Liu, and Suen.
Lastly, once I finish the development of the same, I shall update this question also accordingly. :)